# iOS - Hanling plural noun localization with .stringsdict - not working

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, localization, nslocalizedstring

I am trying to implement plural rules localisation. i.e., I expect "One file..." when the argument is 1, "2 files..." when the argument is 2 and likewise.

I followed the [Apple guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH5-SW1). But I always get the results for plural, even for 1 i.e, "1 files...".

I've created a *Localizable.stringsdict* file with the following content (exactly like the apple guidelines).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>%d messages in your inbox</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
            <string>%#@messages@ in your inbox</string>
            <key>messages</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
                <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
                <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
                <string>d</string>
                <key>one</key>
                <string>One message is</string>
                <key>other</key>
                <string>%d messages are</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

This is how I use this key in code

```
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%d messages in your inbox", @"Message shown for remaining files"), 1]);
```

What could be the problem?. [Here is the sample code I have tried so far.](https://github.com/jsramraj/LocalizationTest)

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20308191/561610 may be useful for you. The only difference that I've noticed is that the number passed as a parameter is of type `long` instead of `integer`. Hope you can find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While debugging, I've noticed that `Localization.stringsdict` file is just ignored. When I've recreated it, everything started to work properly. I guess the original file was created with the wrong type: the correct type should be `Property List`.

I've sent a [pull request](https://github.com/jsramraj/LocalizationTest/pull/1) as you suggested.

Comment: I must have created my .stringsdict with textedit or something. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply the filename `Localizable.stringsdict` that was followed by a whitespace behind... Remove the whitespace in the filename and everything will work fine. No need to recreate the file.

According to the [initial commit that the author gave](https://github.com/jsramraj/LocalizationTest/commit/cae7515d8f886475907399e54e6d98e62bc47237),
you can see that the filename `LocalizationTest/en.lproj/Localizable.stringsdict`  is followed by a whitespace... that's why it is broken. Rename it and everything will go fine.